# How to use mysqli_free_result in OOP style?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am fiddling with mysqli and I have a question about mysqli_free_result() method. (or is it a function? still have to learn OOP).

If I run the code in procedural way I call the function like this:

```
/*
Destroy the result set and free the memory used for it.
*/
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

How do I runt this function in OOP style?

```
$mysqli->free_result(); // does not work. Any ideas why?
```

Should I not free the results and just close the connection after my mysqli work is done, at the end with:

```
$mysqli->close;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis for the method calls. Also, `free_result()` is a method for the [`mysqli_stmt` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) and not the `mysqli` class.

```
$mysqli_stmt->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Ty, for the answer but it still gives this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::free_result()